# Facebook is Fetching Weird URL of my laravel based website

Tags: facebook, laravel-5, og-meta

I am having this link:
http://www.myqourse.com/offer/557/en/Certificate+Business+Professional+-+CBP+Leading+through+change

when I post it on WhatsApp, the link renders perfectly. However, Facebook tries to fetch http://www.myqourse.com/**www.myqourse.com**/offer/557/en/Certificate+Business+Professional+-+CBP+Leading+through+change

Any thoughts why is this is happening?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the full URL in your `og:url` meta tag?

Comment: Yes... You can check in the image I just added to the initial post. I tried removing all meta tags but the result is still the same

Comment: I just tried this on www.myqourse.com and its the same result. it becomes www.myqourse.com/myqourse.com

Comment: I am not sure if this is related but I am having a trouble with twitter as well: https://twittercommunity.com/t/twitter-card-validator-show-no-tags/100756

Comment: _“However, Facebook tries to fetch […]”_ - have you verified this via the access log? (Just because because the debug tool showed your site responding with that output, must not necessarily mean this was what Facebook actually requested.) Double URL encoding seems to be going on somewhere; I wonder if that might have to do with the use of `+` in your URLs, which could easily be problematic. Can you please try with an article URL without any + in it?

Comment: Hi @CBroe , yes, I tried www.myqourse.com and still the same result.

Comment: Will check the log.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! I had a pretender.io middleware, that, was not compatible to my new htaccess. I updated the htaccess and removed pretender.io and forgot to do that to my middleware!

Comment: Could do with a bit more information to make this more explicit and clear for any other users who encounter a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys I appreciate your support.
While investigating the issue, i figured out that i used to use prerender.io before, though i removed the code from my project, it appears i forgot to upload updated Kernel.php (and remove prerender.io from global middleware), now things works perfectly!